# What is the fastest way to extract a sub-array from a numpy 2d array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, optimization

I would like to know the fastest way to extract a sub array from a very large numpy array.
I have an algorithm that needs to run in real time and I often have to extract a sub array which is very time consuming.

Here is how it is currently done:

```
array[max(0,y-q):max(0,y+q+1),max(0,x-q):max(0,x+q+1)]
```

To select a `q*q` array centered in `x, y` from the original one.
In most of the cases I use `q=6`

Is there a way to make it faster?

EDIT:
Here is the code using it

```
res_1 = np.mean(arr_1[max(0,y-q):max(0,y+q+1),max(0,x-q):max(0,x+q+1)])
res_2 = np.mean(arr_2[max(0,y-q):max(0,y+q+1),max(0,x-q):max(0,x+q+1)])
if (arr_0[y, x] - res_1)>0.035 and (arr_0[y, x] - res_2)>0.035:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: What is the shape of the array? `arr.shape`

Comment: It can varies since it is an array from an image, so e.g. (720, 1280) or (1080, 1920)

Comment: The line you posted just creates an array view. No data is copied. This is as fast as it gets. Are you sure this is where your performance problem lies? I suspect the issue is the very next operation which might actually access the data.

Comment: `a[x:x+q, y:y+q]`

Comment: @Homer512 you might be right, I added more of the code in the post. It still seems to be more than half of the time

Comment: One more question: You do this operation only for a single sub-array or a small set of those arrays,not for every entry in the array, right? Because that would be solved faster with a convolution

Comment: I loop through the array, so I am doing this for every x and y

Comment: @Homer512 You were right, using a convolution made it so much faster, thanks

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick benchmark with the `timeit` module. It is as I expected: Creating the subarray consumes almost no time. The mean computation takes all the time. Your real question should be, "How do I improve the mean computation here?"

Interestingly enough, mean runs faster in double precision rather than single precision. I guess the mean function always works in double precision internally.

You could also use `array.sum()` instead of mean. You know the sub-array size, so your comparison could be rewritten as `((arr_0[y, x] * N - res_1)>0.035 * N and ...` I have not benchmarked this.